# rails 3.1 Assets:precompile rake aborted! Permission denied?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, chmod, rails-3.1, chown

I had problems on heroku trying to upload pictures to my app. They were uploaded to AWS but was giving an "Access Denied" error in the database.

Browsing forums I found something similar and it was fixed by giving permission to the app.
Silly me, I did not write down the command, but it was something like

```
chown www ...
```

The problem is that now I apparently do not have permission to write in my app. So when I type

```
rake assets:precompile
```

it returns...

```
$ rake assets:precompile
/Users/sergioabendivar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby /Users/sergioabendivar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production     RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rake aborted!
Permission denied
```

If I tried to delete manually a file from the finder it asks me for the administrator password. However if I try:

```
sudo rake assets:precompile
```

returns

```
.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:316:in `bin_path': can't find gem rake ([">= 0"]) with executable rake (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

I am sure it has something to do something with chown or chmod. But I have no clue what to do...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try navigating to your application root folder and doing

`sudo chown <username> .`

Comment: Yeap... you were right!

   sudo chown -R newuser.newgroup dirname

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
sudo bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: Still not working!
Give me the same error. Apparently it has no rights to write.

Comment: sudo does not work either. .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [minitest-1.6.0, rake-0.8.7, rdoc-2.5.8] (Gem::LoadError)   I am on mac